# shortcut for Anaconda-Spyder-mac version

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Can anyone tell me what's the shortcut in spyder(mac version) to switch spyder to data-frame? please see picture below
grade- dataframe is what I opened from variable explorer, an excel file.

I tried help and looked for all the switch (short cut) from shortcuts summary, but I could not find it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think this is just macOS docking together two separate windows that belong to the same application. So there's no shortcut in Spyder to switch from one to the other, but I think there should be a macOS shortcut to do that.

Comment: +_+ I tried everything still could not figure out if there is a short cut or not

Comment: Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

To see my data frames from my environment (and dictionaries, and NumPy arrays) I click on Variable Explore, find my variable for the data frame and double click on it. It opens in a pop-up window. I can scroll rows and columns there, very convenient. As soon as I click outside of the window it disappears.
I can open a csv file in File pane if I click on it, but it does not have a good formatting.